# How to make responsive circle border around an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

```js
    "use strict";

    const body = document.body;
    const bgColorsBody = ["#ffb457", "#ff96bd", "#9999fb", "#ffe797", "#cffff1"];
    const menu = body.querySelector(".menu");
    const menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll(".menu__item");
    const menuBorder = menu.querySelector(".menu__border");
    let activeItem = menu.querySelector(".active");

    function clickItem(item, index) {

        menu.style.removeProperty("--timeOut");

        if (activeItem == item) return;

        if (activeItem) {
            activeItem.classList.remove("active");
        }


        item.classList.add("active");
        body.style.backgroundColor = bgColorsBody[index];
        activeItem = item;
        offsetMenuBorder(activeItem, menuBorder);


    }

    function offsetMenuBorder(element, menuBorder) {

        const offsetActiveItem = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        const left = Math.floor(offsetActiveItem.left - menu.offsetLeft - (menuBorder.offsetWidth - offsetActiveItem.width) / 2) + "px";
        menuBorder.style.transform = `translate3d(${left}, 0 , 0)`;

    }

    offsetMenuBorder(activeItem, menuBorder);

    menuItems.forEach((item, index) => {

        item.addEventListener("click", () => clickItem(item, index));

    })

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        offsetMenuBorder(activeItem, menuBorder);
        menu.style.setProperty("--timeOut", "none");
    });
```

```css
    html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        --bgColorMenu: #1d1d27;
        --duration: .7s;
    }
    
    html *,
    html *::before,
    html *::after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    
    body {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: #ffb457;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        transition: background-color var(--duration);
    }
    
    .border {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    
    .border svg {
        content: "";
        position: absolute !important;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        stroke-width: 5px;
        fill: none;
        stroke-dasharray: 3000;
        stroke-dashoffset: 3000;
        transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s;
    }
    
    .border svg circle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .border:hover svg {
        transition: stroke-dashoffset 6s;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    
    .menu {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        /* Works well with 100% width  */
        width: 32.05em;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        padding: 0 2.85em;
        position: relative;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: var(--bgColorMenu);
    }
    
    .menu__item {
        all: unset;
        flex-grow: 1;
        z-index: 100;
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 50%;
        align-items: center;
        will-change: transform;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 0.55em 0 0.85em;
        transition: transform var(--timeOut, var(--duration));
    }
    
    .menu__item::before {
        content: "";
        z-index: -1;
        width: 4.2em;
        height: 4.2em;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: scale(0);
        transition: background-color var(--duration), transform var(--duration);
    }
    
    .menu__item.active {
        transform: translate3d(0, -.8em, 0);
    }
    
    .menu__item.active::before {
        transform: scale(1);
        background-color: var(--bgColorItem);
    }
    
    .icon {
        width: 2.6em;
        height: 2.6em;
        stroke: white;
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-width: 1pt;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-dasharray: 400;
    }
    
    .menu__item.active .icon {
        animation: strok 1.5s reverse;
    }
    
    @keyframes strok {
        100% {
            stroke-dashoffset: 400;
        }
    }
    
    .menu__border {
        left: 0;
        bottom: 99%;
        width: 10.9em;
        height: 2.4em;
        position: absolute;
        clip-path: url(#menu);
        will-change: transform;
        background-color: var(--bgColorMenu);
        transition: transform var(--timeOut, var(--duration));
    }
    
    .svg-container {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
        .menu {
            font-size: .8em;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="border">
        <svg> 
        <defs>
       <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
         <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#f093fb;stop-opacity:1" />
         <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#f5576c;stop-opacity:1" />
       </linearGradient>
     </defs>
          <circle cx="23" cy="26" r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3">
      </svg>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <menu class="menu">

        <button class="menu__item active" style="--bgColorItem: #ff8c00;">
      <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M3.8,6.6h16.4"/>
        <path d="M20.2,12.1H3.8"/>
        <path d="M3.8,17.5h16.4"/>
      </svg>
    </button>

        <button class="menu__item" style="--bgColorItem: #f54888;">
      <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path  d="M6.7,4.8h10.7c0.3,0,0.6,0.2,0.7,0.5l2.8,7.3c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3v5.6c0,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,0.8H3.8
        C3.4,19.3,3,19,3,18.5v-5.6c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3L6,5.3C6.1,5,6.4,4.8,6.7,4.8z"/>
        <path  d="M3.4,12.9H8l1.6,2.8h4.9l1.5-2.8h4.6"/>
      </svg>
    </button>

        <button class="menu__item" style="--bgColorItem: #4343f5;">
      <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path  d="M3.4,11.9l8.8,4.4l8.4-4.4"/>
      <path  d="M3.4,16.2l8.8,4.5l8.4-4.5"/>
      <path  d="M3.7,7.8l8.6-4.5l8,4.5l-8,4.3L3.7,7.8z"/>
    </svg>
    </button>

        <button class="menu__item" style="--bgColorItem: #e0b115;"> 
      <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
        <path  d="M5.1,3.9h13.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2v13.9c0,0.6-0.5,1.2-1.2,1.2H5.1c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2V5.1
          C3.9,4.4,4.4,3.9,5.1,3.9z"/>
        <path  d="M4.2,9.3h15.6"/>
        <path  d="M9.1,9.5v10.3"/>
    </svg>
    </button>

        <button class="menu__item" style="--bgColorItem:#65ddb7;">
      <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" >
        <path  d="M5.1,3.9h13.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2v13.9c0,0.6-0.5,1.2-1.2,1.2H5.1c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2V5.1
          C3.9,4.4,4.4,3.9,5.1,3.9z"/>
        <path  d="M5.5,20l9.9-9.9l4.7,4.7"/>
        <path  d="M10.4,8.8c0,0.9-0.7,1.6-1.6,1.6c-0.9,0-1.6-0.7-1.6-1.6C7.3,8,8,7.3,8.9,7.3C9.7,7.3,10.4,8,10.4,8.8z"/>
      </svg>
    </button>

        <div class="menu__border"></div>

    </menu>

    <div class="svg-container">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 202.9 45.5">
      <clipPath id="menu" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.0049285362247413 0.021978021978022)">
        <path  d="M6.7,45.5c5.7,0.1,14.1-0.4,23.3-4c5.7-2.3,9.9-5,18.1-10.5c10.7-7.1,11.8-9.2,20.6-14.3c5-2.9,9.2-5.2,15.2-7
          c7.1-2.1,13.3-2.3,17.6-2.1c4.2-0.2,10.5,0.1,17.6,2.1c6.1,1.8,10.2,4.1,15.2,7c8.8,5,9.9,7.1,20.6,14.3c8.3,5.5,12.4,8.2,18.1,10.5
          c9.2,3.6,17.6,4.2,23.3,4H6.7z"/>
      </clipPath>
    </svg>
    </div>
```

(First run the code) In above code, I want to make the `.border` circle animation (when you run code and enter the mouse into the page, you can see the border on the top left) around the `.menu__item` circles after click.
when the user clicked on the buttons I want to make that border with animation somehow around the menu buttons but I do not know how to do this responsively.

Comment: Learn to use the [ <> ] button in the Stack Overflow editor, and your code will run as an SO snippet

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I added it. now you can use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a reusable svg `<symbol>` and add it to your icon elements like so:

```
<!-- circle symbol -->
<svg class="svgHidden" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
  <symbol id="circle-ani" overflow="visible">
    <circle fill="none" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="70%">
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Modified icon:

```
  <button class="menu__item active" style="--bgColorItem: #ff8c00;">
    <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M3.8,6.6h16.4" />
      <path d="M20.2,12.1H3.8" />
      <path d="M3.8,17.5h16.4" />
      <use class="circle" href="#circle-ani" />
    </svg>
  </button>
```

### Additional css

You will need to **make sure, the overflow is visible**, since the circle element is exceeding the boundaries of your icon's viewBox:

```
.svgHidden{
  position:absolute;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.menu__item svg{
  overflow:visible
}

.circle{
  stroke-width:0
}
.menu__item.active
.circle{
  stroke-width:1.5
}
```

### Modified example

```js
"use strict";

const body = document.body;
const bgColorsBody = ["#ffb457", "#ff96bd", "#9999fb", "#ffe797", "#cffff1"];
const menu = body.querySelector(".menu");
const menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll(".menu__item");
const menuBorder = menu.querySelector(".menu__border");
let activeItem = menu.querySelector(".active");

function clickItem(item, index) {

  menu.style.removeProperty("--timeOut");

  if (activeItem == item) return;

  if (activeItem) {
    activeItem.classList.remove("active");
  }


  item.classList.add("active");
  body.style.backgroundColor = bgColorsBody[index];
  activeItem = item;
  offsetMenuBorder(activeItem, menuBorder);


}

function offsetMenuBorder(element, menuBorder) {

  const offsetActiveItem = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  const left = Math.floor(offsetActiveItem.left - menu.offsetLeft - (menuBorder.offsetWidth - offsetActiveItem.width) / 2) + "px";
  menuBorder.style.transform = `translate3d(${left}, 0 , 0)`;

}

offsetMenuBorder(activeItem, menuBorder);

menuItems.forEach((item, index) => {

  item.addEventListener("click", () => clickItem(item, index));

})

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  offsetMenuBorder(activeItem, menuBorder);
  menu.style.setProperty("--timeOut", "none");
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  --bgColorMenu: #1d1d27;
  --duration: .7s;
}

html *,
html *::before,
html *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #ffb457;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color var(--duration);
}

.border {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.border svg {
  content: "";
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 3000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3000;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s;
}

.border svg circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.border:hover svg {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 6s;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  /* Works well with 100% width  */
  width: 32.05em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 2.85em;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: var(--bgColorMenu);
}

.menu__item {
  all: unset;
  flex-grow: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  will-change: transform;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.55em 0 0.85em;
  transition: transform var(--timeOut, var(--duration));
}

.menu__item::before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  width: 4.2em;
  height: 4.2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: background-color var(--duration), transform var(--duration);
}

.menu__item.active {
  transform: translate3d(0, -.8em, 0);
}

.menu__item.active::before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: var(--bgColorItem);
}

.icon {
  width: 2.6em;
  height: 2.6em;
  stroke: white;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 1pt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 400;
}

.menu__item.active .icon {
  animation: strok 1.5s reverse;
}

@keyframes strok {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 400;
  }
}

.menu__border {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 99%;
  width: 10.9em;
  height: 2.4em;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: url(#menu);
  will-change: transform;
  background-color: var(--bgColorMenu);
  transition: transform var(--timeOut, var(--duration));
}

.svg-container {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
  .menu {
    font-size: .8em;
  }
}

.svgHidden {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu__item svg {
  overflow: visible
}

.circle {
  stroke-width: 0
}

.menu__item.active .circle {
  stroke-width: 1.5
}
```

```html
<!-- circle element -->
<svg class="svgHidden" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
  <symbol id="circle-ani" overflow="visible">
    <circle fill="none" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="70%">
  </symbol>
</svg>

<menu class="menu">
  <button class="menu__item active" style="--bgColorItem: #ff8c00;">
    <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M3.8,6.6h16.4" />
      <path d="M20.2,12.1H3.8" />
      <path d="M3.8,17.5h16.4" />
      <use class="circle" href="#circle-ani" />
    </svg>
  </button>

  <button class="menu__item" style="--bgColorItem: #f54888;">
    <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M6.7,4.8h10.7c0.3,0,0.6,0.2,0.7,0.5l2.8,7.3c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3v5.6c0,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,0.8H3.8
        C3.4,19.3,3,19,3,18.5v-5.6c0-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.3L6,5.3C6.1,5,6.4,4.8,6.7,4.8z" />
      <path d="M3.4,12.9H8l1.6,2.8h4.9l1.5-2.8h4.6" />
      <use class="circle" href="#circle-ani" />
    </svg>
  </button>

  <button class="menu__item" style="--bgColorItem: #4343f5;">
    <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M3.4,11.9l8.8,4.4l8.4-4.4" />
      <path d="M3.4,16.2l8.8,4.5l8.4-4.5" />
      <path d="M3.7,7.8l8.6-4.5l8,4.5l-8,4.3L3.7,7.8z" />
      <use class="circle" href="#circle-ani" />
    </svg>
  </button>

  <button class="menu__item" style="--bgColorItem: #e0b115;">
    <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M5.1,3.9h13.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2v13.9c0,0.6-0.5,1.2-1.2,1.2H5.1c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2V5.1
          C3.9,4.4,4.4,3.9,5.1,3.9z" />
      <path d="M4.2,9.3h15.6" />
      <path d="M9.1,9.5v10.3" />
      <use class="circle" href="#circle-ani" />
    </svg>
  </button>

  <button class="menu__item" style="--bgColorItem:#65ddb7;">
    <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M5.1,3.9h13.9c0.6,0,1.2,0.5,1.2,1.2v13.9c0,0.6-0.5,1.2-1.2,1.2H5.1c-0.6,0-1.2-0.5-1.2-1.2V5.1
          C3.9,4.4,4.4,3.9,5.1,3.9z" />
      <path d="M5.5,20l9.9-9.9l4.7,4.7" />
      <path d="M10.4,8.8c0,0.9-0.7,1.6-1.6,1.6c-0.9,0-1.6-0.7-1.6-1.6C7.3,8,8,7.3,8.9,7.3C9.7,7.3,10.4,8,10.4,8.8z" />
      <use class="circle" href="#circle-ani" />
    </svg>
  </button>

  <div class="menu__border"></div>

</menu>

<div class="svg-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 202.9 45.5">
    <clipPath id="menu" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="scale(0.0049285362247413 0.021978021978022)">
      <path d="M6.7,45.5c5.7,0.1,14.1-0.4,23.3-4c5.7-2.3,9.9-5,18.1-10.5c10.7-7.1,11.8-9.2,20.6-14.3c5-2.9,9.2-5.2,15.2-7
          c7.1-2.1,13.3-2.3,17.6-2.1c4.2-0.2,10.5,0.1,17.6,2.1c6.1,1.8,10.2,4.1,15.2,7c8.8,5,9.9,7.1,20.6,14.3c8.3,5.5,12.4,8.2,18.1,10.5
          c9.2,3.6,17.6,4.2,23.3,4H6.7z" />
    </clipPath>
  </svg>
</div>
```